# TypeError: this._initChildViewStorage is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following code

```
 var contentView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        template: _.template('Hi, I\'m a view! pass me something: <%= something %>'),

        initialize: function(options){
            console.log("initialized itemview");         }

    });
   var contentCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend();

    contentCollectionView({
        itemView: contentView
    });
```

I am not rendering anything yet, and I get the error

```
TypeError: this._initChildViewStorage is not a function
```

If I remove the line

```
   contentCollectionView({
            itemView: contentView
        });
```

I do not get the error.

I can show my contentView by itself no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that I assumed I could just add functionality to  contentCollectionView without starting a new instance of it.

So what I needed to do was

```
var contentCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend();

var myview =   new contentCollectionView({
        itemView: contentView
    });
```

Comment: For me, I just forgot to put "new" in there.